# Docker configure Nginx and letsencrypt problem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I have a problem getting the nginx and letsencrypt set up with docker.

Below is my docker-compose file. nginx on port 80:80 and website on port 80:8000

when I docker-compose up --build or just docker-compose up, website and nginx are not set up saying that the port 80 is already in use.

I have followed this tutorial --> https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71
I set up everything just like what the tutorial said.

What have I done wrong? please help me out.
Did I mess up with the directories? attached is the tree view of /var/www/kiwi/data 
my app is in /var/www/kiwi.

[image]
[image]
[image: nginx]
[image]

Comment: Your problem is not related with letsencrypt, you simply don't need to expose your website container port like this, you just need to expose nginx ports

Comment: Your second screenshot is sideways.  Attaching screenshots of terminal windows to SO questions isn't usually a good practice; can you replace these with a plain-text description of what commands you've run, copies of relevant application source, and the textual output they produce?  I'm not really sure how I'd take these screenshots and use them to reproduce your issue.